# php checkebox with variable

Tags: php, sql

This is my code that has checkboxes

```
echo '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=""> 
      <p>
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="'.$i.'"value="$r1" id="cb'.$i.'" />
         i' . $r1 . '
      </label><br /> ';
$i=$i+1;
echo '<label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="'.$i.'"value="$r2" id="cb'.$i.'" />
        ' . $r2 .
     '</label><br />';
$i=$i+1;
```

add here I try to khnow if it is checked or no

```
if( !empty($_POST[$j]) ) //// here my prob 
{
    $results=$_POST[$j];
    if($results=$row[0]){
       $s=$s+1;$t=$t+1;
    }else{
       $t=$t+1;
    }
}
```

I am having a problem in the line `!empty($_POST[$j])` I get false all the time, but there is no error. I dont know if this is possible. But this is the only way to do this. because my check is created from my database information.

I need help plz :) sry for my english.

Comment: Clean your code, please. What is your $j value?

Comment: We need a bit more context and code in order to understand what you're having trouble with. On that note, avoid putting HTML in your PHP code AT ALL COSTS. The paradigm is to have an HTML layout that you would inject your PHP into. Like an `index.php` file that would look like a regular HTML file but you would be able to use `<?php //Your php code here ?>` to create whatever dynamic functionality that you need.

Comment: The line that you say that there is a problem is most probably because it is specting a form submit and a variable on your post that the name is defined somewhere in your code on this variable `$j`. First off all you need to check where is this variable been setted. Show us at least this.

Comment: var_dump $j and see what you get

Answer (score 1):

**HTML MARKUP**

First, add required whitespaces in between your attributes and apply the same strategy for including variables in your output using single-quotes:

```
name="'.$i.'"value="$r1"
```

should become

```
name="'.$i.'" value="'.$r1.'"
```

You do this to assure proper markup in your HTML. This way you can make sure that all proper browsers have no trouble interpreting your HTML code.

**INPUT:CHECKBOX AND HOW IT WORKS**

Next, please understand what the `value` attribute in your `input` actually does.

Example:

- If `value="1"` and the checkbox is checked, then the result sent in the request will be 1
- If `value="1"` and the checkbox is **not** checked, then no result will be sent in your request

This means that your `value` attribute doesn't have to be set to `$r1`. Its ok if you just set it to `1` for instance.

If you set `value` to `1`, this means that you could also do this:

```
if($_POST[$j]=='1')
```

although it might be better to not check for the `value` but just to check if the key in `$_POST` is set.

*Why?*

Because that way the part of your PHP script which evaluates the request coming from the form, doesn't have to know what the actual value of the checkbox was. *If* a checkbox is checked, you will always find its `name` attribute as `key` in `$_POST` (or in `$_GET`, if that is what you use).

Note: If you don't set the value of a checkbox, the vast majority of browsers will send `on` as the value, if the checkbox is checked.

**EMPTY() OR ISSET()**

Next, understand the difference between `empty()` and `isset()`.

[Follow this link to learn more about how these functions work and how they differ](http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/#axzz2ng4AGo9Q)

Change your `empty()` call to `isset()`:

```
if( !empty($_POST[$j]) )
```

becomes

```
if( isset($_POST[$j]) )
```

I find the latter to be more clear simply because it follows non-reversed logic. But in the end you can choose to use `!empty()` if you prefer,but remember that `empty()` will return `true` if the checked value is an empty string, if it is a boolean `false`, if it is an empty array and even if it is `null`.

**INTEGRITY**

Finally, make sure that `$j` has the same value as `$i` (which is applied as `name` attribute to your checkbox) when generating the checkboxes in the code before. Otherwise your condition will not check for the correct value (or rather *key* in the `$_POST` superglobal).